# Can't authenticate with router on 802.1x network

Tags: wireless-access-point, 802.1x

I need to set up an access point in my dorm as wifi doesn't make it to my room. I have an ethernet outlet which doesn't even require auth (wifi, on the contrary, does. You need university credentials which I have) and it works just fine connecting a PC. But I want to connect an AP to it, in order to create my local network and connect my phone to it as well.

I followed this [guide](https://enjoykhg.blogspot.com/2017/12/how-to-configure-openwrt-router-8021x.html), but at the command:

```
wpa_supplicant -D wired -i eth0 -c /etc/config/wpa.conf
```

it gets stuck with this message looping

```
eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
```

I am using an Asus RT-AC51U and a macbook. What can I do?

Comment: Please post the verbose logs of `wpa_supplicant -d -d ...`.

Comment: @grawity how do I do that?

Comment: You might want to engage with your university's IT dept. They might be able to advise a little better than we can.

Comment: @AndreaCRD Run the same command, with some `-d` options added.

Comment: @grawity here's the screenshot
http://img-hosting.foxsash.com/qP3hU5O/image.png

Comment: Yeah, you can't insert it in that specific place, as the word `wired` is actually a parameter for `-D`... easiest to just put it at the end.

Comment: Make sure and double check your university's policies before you actually do this.  Chances are that it's against the IT policies, and you may get in trouble for it when the university's IT department finds out about it (and they _will_ find out, unless they're completely incompetent).